# Mocha timeout using selenium-driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am trying to launch my mocha tests using selenium-driver but I got this error : https://gist.github.com/Clemzd/f7bbaa77c492ee288765#file-gistfile1-txt.

My selenium-server is well started because I'm able to run a chrome session. 
Here is the code I used to launch my mocha tests : https://github.com/Clemzd/paige-tests.

I tried to increase the timeout for mocha but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`selenium-webdriver/testing` seems to have a hard time with mocha versions above 1.20. You can get this error to go away by changing the mocha dependency in your package.json to look like this:

`mocha: "~1.20.1"`

Comment: I've had better luck with `1.18.2`